# use a value instead of an index in array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I can't seem to format my array that is being saved to localStorage.
Can you change the index value of an array?
I have an array object like this:

```
const myArray = [{id: 41, name: "x"}, {id: 42, name: "y"}]
```

But I want to make it like this:

```
const myArray = [ 41: {id:41, name:"x" }, 42: {id:41, name:"y" }}
```

So the id of the object becomes the index of the array

If that is not possible then like this should be fine:

```
const myArray = [ {41: {id:41, name:"x"} }, {42: {id:41, name:"y"}}]
```

So basically the id of the object becomes either the index or a container object for that object.

Comment: Actual arrays in JavaScript can only have a zero-based, continuous numeric index. What you want, can only be accomplished by using an object instead of an array, and giving it _properties_ with the names `41` and `42`.

Comment: _"If that is not possible then like this should be fine"_ - _that_ kind of structure is possible, but - what is your actual _question_ relating to this now? Are you asking to how to dynamically create it? If so, from what exact input data?

Comment: "use a value instead of an index in array object" in an array, no. in an object, yes. Your third example, creating an array of objects, would be a fine solution. You could also make the whole thing an object, and loop through it with `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1))` (if that's what you want)

Comment: You can create a [sparse array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays), but there's no literal syntax for creating it. And also it's not recommended to create sparse arrays anyway.

Comment: why not take an (additional) object as reference to the objects with the same `id` as key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly change the key of an element in an array to a specific value like an object's property. Butyou can create an object where the keys are the IDs and the values are the corresponding objects.

```
const myArray = [{id: 41, name: "x"}, {id: 42, name: "y"}];
const myObject = {};

// Convert array to object
myArray.forEach(item => {
    myObject[item.id] = item;
});

// Now myObject will look like:
// { 41: {id:41, name:"x"}, 42: {id:42, name:"y"} }

// If you still need it as an array of objects with IDs as keys:
const newArray = Object.keys(myObject).map(key => ({ [key]: myObject[key] }));

// Now newArray will look like:
// [ {41: {id:41, name:"x"} }, {42: {id:42, name:"y"}} ]
```